# Export an endpoint function with module?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to export a function from a js module into app.js. However, it throws an error when executes. What am I doing wrong? I thought module.exports was the way to do it and you can export a function not just an object.

```
sms_list = require('./api/sms-list.js')
sms_list_scan = require('./api/sms-list-scan.js')

app.get('/sms-list/scan', sms_list_scan)

app.get('/sms-list', sms_list)

var sms_list = function(req, res) {
    res.send('ok') 
 }

 module.exports.sms_list = sms_list

route.js:202
    throw new Error(msg);
    ^

 Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]
```

Comment: Welcome! It's a good idea when your code causes an error to include the text of the error with your question. Not always the entire stack trace, but enough for the meaning to be clear. Cheers!

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: Is all of this code in one file?

Comment: Try `module.exports = sms_list;`

Comment: That didn't work.

Comment: What NullDev wrote should work. Maybe you didn't do it for both functions. Please edit the question so it's easier to tell the files apart.